# Query syntax for getting a list as a list of different types?

Tags: linq

I have a query that fetches books, I'm new to LINQ so I don't know the syntax:

```
var books = (from book in db.Books
             join borrow in db.Borrows on book equals borrow.Book
             select new BookDTO { Title = book.Title, 
                                  Borrows = book.Borrows.ToList() }).ToList(); // book.Borrows.ToList() <- use dto's instead
```

How can I select `Book.Borrows` as a list of objects (BorrowDTO's)? Is there something like `Borrows = new List<BorrowDTO>(book.Borrows)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.Select()` to project the list into a different type.  So instead of this:

```
Borrows = book.Borrows.ToList()
```

you would have something like this:

```
Borrows = book.Borrows.Select(b => new BorrowDTO { /* properties here */ }).ToList()
```

Note that, depending on your data source, there *may* be more efficient ways to approach selecting your data.  If you're pulling directly from LINQ To Entities then you *may* run into problems trying to materialize a type within the query that isn't known to the DB, or any other operation that can't be translated into SQL.  It's also not necessarily wise to toss in a bunch of `.ToList()` operations without a specific purpose.

But that's all theoretical at this point in the question.  Based on the code shown and on LINQ syntax itself, you can select from a list just fine.  (I'd even recomment using the extension method syntax more than the query syntax that you currently use.  Personal preference of course, but I find it easier and more intuitive to build nested operations like this.  Though you can just as well use the `from ... select ...` syntax after `Borrows =`, I would imagine.)

Answer (score 0):

Just `select book.Borrows` instead of creating a new temporal object.

That query is going to return a `IEnumerable` of the `Borrows` type; and you'll be able to iterate through it and convert it into a List if you please